# Web API Filter on Optionset value

Tags: odata, microsoft-dynamics, webapi

I need to filter on an optionset Value in stead of on the Id
For example, the entityfield is 'my_choices' and has three optionsetvalues:

- One (9487500)
- Two (9487501)
- Three (9487502)

I have tried ?$filter=(my_choices/Value eq 'Two')

But this does not work... (Could not find a property named 'Value' on type 'Edm.Int32')

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen and I know you cannot filter optionset Value based on it's localized name.

You will get localized name in response of your request.